# How to generate relationship in database using EF database approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm using vs 2013, and added Entity Framework using the Database first approach. My scenario is that, my database doesn't have yet relationship but the four tables already have primary key. Can I use the vs 2013 to set the relationship between my entities? or Should I do it in my SQL Server database ? I'm new to ORM (EF). Thanks for any helpful answer/guides.

Comment: In my own opinion, doing the relationship first in sql server is better than manually create it in edmx. If you want to create it manually then you should change your approach to model first

Comment: Is there a way to do it in generated diagram ?

Comment: I have not tried it manually using diagram. My guess is right click show model browser and from there you can explore the model and add some model mapping